# How can I select all the default values that start with the character 'A'?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using SSRS.

I have one parameters, it is a list where I can select multiple values.

The Available values came from a query that gave something like this (example data):

| Value_Field | Label_Field |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Apple |
| 1 | Banana |
| 2 | Apple tee |

So, in my report, I can select one or multiple values.

What I want to do is when the user use my report, I want the default values to be all the values that begin with `A`.

In this example, I want `Apple` and `Apple tee` to be selected everytime an user open my report.

I tried to use the regex, but no succes.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your parameter dataset query for the available values is the following

```
SELECT Value_Field, Label_Field
FROM mytable
```

You have to create a second dataset with the filter and set it as your parameter default values

```
SELECT Value_Field, Label_Field
FROM mytable
WHERE Label_Field LIKE 'A%'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I usually put my values in a temp table and add a Default Value column that has the Available value when it matches. Then I update the other Default Values with another available value.

```
DECLARE @SEARCH VARCHAR(20) = 'A'

SELECT *, 
    IIF(Label_Field LIKE @SEARCH + '%', Label_Field, '') AS DEFAULT_VALUE 
INTO #TEMP_VALUES
FROM CURRENT_QUERY

UPDATE #TEMP_VALUES
SET DEFAULT_VALUE = (SELECT MAX(DEFAULT_VALUE) FROM #TEMP_VALUES
WHERE DEFAULT_VALUE = ''

SELECT * FROM #TEMP_VALUES
```

I used a parameter for the search value to make it easy to change if necessary. If it may change, you can add it as a hidden parameter on the report so you can change it easily when needed.